# How to read a GML file on Spyder, Anaconda using networkX

Tags: python, anaconda, networkx, spyder

I am a very beginner on coding. Could you please help me how I can read / print a gml file on Python Anaconda using networkX? I installed the library and code looks like this:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.read_gml("gebaude.gml")

print(nx.info(g))
```

and after I run it, console looks like this:

```
runfile('C:/Users/aksupi/Desktop/Experiment1.py', wdir='C:/Users/aksupi/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\aksupi\Desktop\Experiment1.py", line 10, in <module>
    g = nx.read_gml("gebaude.gml")

  File "<decorator-gen-812>", line 2, in read_gml

  File "C:\Users\aksupi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 213, in _open_file
    fobj = _dispatch_dict[ext](path, mode=mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gebaude.gml'
[enter image description here][2]
```

What is the problem? Where do I need to put the gml file on my computer?

I will be looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Best regards,

Pinar

Comment: Without folder reference or absolute path in `.gml` file, you expect the `.gml` file resides in same directory as `.py` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the absolute path (the full path) of the file or if you want to use a relative path (in this case the name) you need to set the current working directory accordingly. In this case the working directory is `C:/Users/aksupi/Desktop` (you can see it in the `wdir` of the `runfile` call that Spyder does when running a file) so the file needs to be at `C:/Users/aksupi/Desktop/` (so its absolute path will be `C:/Users/aksupi/Desktop/gebaude.gml`).

Just in case, inside Spyder the current working directory is shown in the top right:

[image]